# Более правильный подход к организации универсального метода под похожий род задач

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Вот есть задача, определить в некоторых методах работы с базой данных (добавить запись, модифицировать запись, удалить запись) и необходимо убедиться в одном случае, что запись существует, в другом случае, что пользователь с такими параметрами уже существует.

И для этого в 2-х случаях нужно проверять как просто rs.next(), в другом случае! rs.next() и получается так, что нужно создавать 2 идентичных метод принимающих одни и те же входные параметры: буловый SQL запрос, SQL запрос на выпонение, ответ если все хорошо и ответ, если ложь и разница только в одном, что в одном случае есть "!" в другом случае его нет.

Отсюда вопрос, как можно сделать одним универсальным метод на эти случае?
Я уже думал делать глобальную стринговуе переменную, например String executableMethod и в каждом из методов (создание записи, модификация и удаление) присваивать ей значения например executableMethod = insert; и в другом методе = modify, и в 3-м = delete соответственно и передавать в одним метод этот стринг. Далее в методе проверять.

Посему вопрос, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как это сделать лучше?
Скриншот кода упомянутых методов в приложении.
Ах да, программа на Java.
База данных локальная SQLite, хотя по сути это не так важно какая база, логика одна.
Код всех упомянутых методов.

```
public void insertUserData(String SQLiteName, String SQLiteSurname,
                           String SQLitePosition, double SQLiteSalary,
                           double SQLiteExperience) {
    try {
        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MainEmployeeData(Name, Surname, Position, Salary, Experience)" +
                "VALUES('" + SQLiteName + "', '" + SQLiteSurname + "', '" + SQLitePosition + "', " +
                "'" + SQLiteSalary + "', '" + SQLiteExperience + "')";

        boolSqlQuery = "SELECT Name, Surname " + "FROM MainEmployeeData WHERE Name = \"" +
                SQLiteName + "\" AND Surname = \"" + SQLiteSurname + "\"";
        trueAnswer = "Data was successfully saved!";
        falseAnswer = "Record with such parameters already exists!";
        existenceCheckerInsertion(boolSqlQuery, sqlQuery, trueAnswer, falseAnswer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void deleteEmployeeData(String employeeName, String employeeSurname) {
    try {
        trueAnswer = "Data was successfully deleted!";
        falseAnswer = "No record with such parameters exists!";

        boolSqlQuery = "SELECT Name, Surname FROM MainEmployeeData WHERE Name = \"" +
                employeeName + "\" AND Surname = \"" + employeeSurname + "\"";

        sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM MainEmployeeData WHERE Name = \"" + employeeName + "\"" +
                "AND Surname = \"" + employeeSurname + "\"";

        recordExistenceChecker(boolSqlQuery, sqlQuery, trueAnswer,
                falseAnswer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public <E> void modifyEmployeeDataInDB(String getParameterToBeModified,
                                       E getOldParameter, E getNewParameter) {
    try {
        trueAnswer = "Data was successfully changed!";
        falseAnswer = "No record with such parameter found!";

        boolSqlQuery = "SELECT " + getParameterToBeModified + " FROM MainEmployeeData" +
                " WHERE " + getParameterToBeModified + " = " + "\"" + getOldParameter + "\"";

        sqlQuery = "UPDATE MainEmployeeData SET " + getParameterToBeModified +
                " = \"" + getNewParameter + "\" WHERE " + getParameterToBeModified +
                " = " + "\"" + getOldParameter + "\"";

        recordExistenceChecker(boolSqlQuery, sqlQuery, trueAnswer,
                falseAnswer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void recordExistenceChecker(String getBoolSqlQuery,
                                    String getSqlQuery,
                                    String getTrueAnswer,
                                    String getFalseAnswer) throws SQLException {
    stmt = connect.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(getBoolSqlQuery);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    if (rs.next()) {
        stmt.execute(getSqlQuery);
        System.out.print(getTrueAnswer);
        stmt.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println(getFalseAnswer);
    }

    stmt.close();
}

private void existenceCheckerInsertion(String getBoolSqlQuery,
                                       String getSqlQuery,
                                       String getTrueAnswer,
                                       String getFalseAnswer) throws SQLException {
    stmt = connect.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(getBoolSqlQuery);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    if (!rs.next()) {
        stmt.execute(getSqlQuery);
        System.out.print(getTrueAnswer);
        stmt.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println(getFalseAnswer);
    }

    stmt.close();
}
```

Comment: Стандартно - это `[INSERT | UPDATE] ... WHERE [NOT] EXISTS (SELECT ...)`. Подзапрос выполняет отбор по заданным параметрам, и модификация/вставка выполняется лишь в случае, если его результат [не] пуст. В частных случаях - запрос упрощается за счёт введения в источник данных дополнительных таблиц с требуемыми условиями отбора. Само собой, отпадают варианты модификации данных с использованием **VALUES**, т.е. `... VALUES (...)` заменяется на `... SELECT ... [FROM DUAL]`. Итог выполнения запроса анализируется на основании количества модифицированных записей и/или доп. запросов.

Comment: Нет, вы не совсем поняли вопрос. Вопрос заключается в том, как обьяденить показанные методы recordExistenceChecker и existenceCheckerInsertion, чтобы он был универсален для всех методов которые выше.

Comment: упростить с помощью хибернейта и спринг дата. упрощается просто до 3 строчек кода

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Можно немного подробнее? Просто специфика задачи в том, что это нужно сделать без всяких фреймворков а просто влоб.

Comment: А зачем вы перед выполнением delete проверяете наличие записи ? delete не вернет никаких ошибок и ничего не удалит, в случае, если такой записи нет. После выполнения операции delete (с помощью `executeUpdate()`, вместо `execute()`) вы можете получить количество обработанных записей и если оно 0 - значит delete ничего не удалил, так как было нечего удалять. А если в таблице есть уникальный ключ по полям name,surname то вы можете использовать `insert ... on conflict ignore` и он так же вернет 1 если запись удалось вставить и 0 если запись не вставлена, так как она уже была.

Comment: Любые действия с БД можно выполнить одним запросом. И выполнение 2х запросов вместо одного не только медленно, но и потенциально ведет к ошибкам. потому что между выполнением bool запроса и реального в БД что то измениться и вы например вставите второго пользователя, потому что в момент выполнения select пользователя еще не было, а в момент insert он уже есть. Поэтому _необходимо_ выполнять любые операции с БД атомарно, за один запрос

Comment: тогда вам это решение не подходит. и спринг, и хибернейт - фреймворки

Comment: @Mike Надо, чтобы он в консоле писал существует такая запись или нет, потому и проверяю.

Comment: так он и будет писать, если проверите чем завершился insert/delete. `if(stmt.executeUpdate(SqlQuery)==0) { print "yes answer";} else { "NO answer" }` или наоборот. при желании можно просто сообщения наоборот передать

Comment: @Mike Вы имеете в виду использовать COUNT(*) и проверять равен ли  он нулю?

Comment: НЕТ. прочитайте что я написал внимательнее и прочитайте описание функции `executeUpdate()`. Эта функция возвращает количество реально измененных запросом записей. delete вернет 0 если не чего было удалять и 1 (или больше) если он что то удалил. Так же insert и update возвращают количество вставленных или измененных записей, по которому ясно, что было в БД до их выполнения

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за комментарий и идею! Буду разбираться!

Comment: А так же посмотрите примеры работы с БД, например http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/update/  особое внимание обратите на то, что в запросах на местах параметров пишут знаки `?` а потом привязывают значения. Ваш текущих вариант приведет к ошибке в случае, если кто нибудь в имени укажет кавычку (которая сломает ваши кавычки) и при желании, правильно расставив кавычки в имени, хакер может вообще выполнить произвольный sql-запрос (sql-инъекция)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое!